If $(κ_i)_{i∈ λ}$ is a cardinal sequence of length $λ$: do it exists a bijection from $λ$ into $λ$ such that $κ_{f(i)}\le κ_{f(j)}$ if $i<j$?
Let be $\lambda$ a cardinal so that let be $(\kappa_i)_{i\in\lambda}$ a cardinal sequence of length $\lambda$: I ask if it exists a bijection $f$ from $\lambda$ into $\lambda$ such that the proposition
$$
(\forall p)(\forall q)
\biggl(
\Bigl(
\bigl((p\in\lambda)\wedge(q\in\lambda)
\Bigr)
\to
\Bigl(
(p<q)\to\bigl(\kappa_{f(p)}\le\kappa_{f(q)}\bigr)
\Bigr)
\biggr)
$$
holds. I am searching for a formal proof: could someone help me, please?

Think about the case $\lambda = \omega$ first. You're then more or less asking: "does every countable set of cardinals have order-type $\omega$?" Do you think this is true?
